# Margin top calculations in animate jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to subtract `10%` from the window `height/2` but with no result , what is the problem ?

```
var loadingMargin = $(window).height()/2; 
$(".loading .sk-circle").animate({
   marginTop: loadingMargin-10+"%" 
});
```

Comment: Use `loadingMargin*0.9`

Comment: thanks bro but it  means that we do our mathematical operations and store it in variables then put it in animate() not do it in animate !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate `90`percentage and set value

```
var loadingMargin = ($(window).height() / 2) * .9;
$(".loading .sk-circle").animate({
  marginTop: loadingMargin
});
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked but it means that  we cannot do mathematical operations in animate() ?

Comment: @user3879222 you can do addition and subtraction `-=10` or `+=10` , _[`Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)_

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this even,

```
var loadingMargin = ($(window).height())/2, //window Height /2
    calMargin = loadingMargin*0.1, //10% of window height
    substractVal = (loadingMargin - calMargin); //substract value

    $(".loading .sk-circle").animate({
         marginTop : substractVal
    });
```